# Date differences in Power BI- Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to get a Days Interval column through getting the difference between today's Date  and a column Refresh date in Power Query. How do I go about it?

I want to do this in Power Query:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

= DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())-[Refresh Date]